# how to protect Webservice against Denial of Service attack?

Tags: delphi, iis, denial-of-service, webbroker

What can I do to protect Web service/ WebBroker application against Denial of Service attack? the attack causes IIS to create huge amount of webbroker instances at the same moment of time. the webbroker does not have enough time to start and response before a new request comes. that sometimes causes the webbroker to crash. Is there some sort of limitation of request per minute or some way to put requests into the queue?

thank you.

Comment: not sure exactly how to do this in IIS, however, what you may want to research is: how to check how many connection does IP X had in the past 10 seconds, if that number is >= 10 then any other connection will be forced to disconnect, also, you may want to limit the amount of RAM you allocate per IP, as an alternative to IIS, I would strongly recommend Apache as it is more flexible and open to your desires...

Comment: CloudFlare has a service that automatically try to protect your site against DSA. You my try it. Implementing one on your own could be difficult.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc750213.aspx#XSLTsection126121120120   .. better asked in serverfault I guess.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29865192/1614973) for Parse.com service but most of it, including **Security by Obscurity**, applies to other services.